# How can the localization property of the edge mode in topological insulator/quantum hall system be manifested through the effective action?

Tags: condensed-matter, classical-electrodynamics, topological-field-theory, topological-insulators, quantum-hall-effect

To be more specific, we can write down the Chern-Simons term from coupling the system to EM to describe the 2d quantum hall system and its derivative respect to the EM field gives the current. How can we see that the current is indeed localized on the boundary? Or, if the EM field is spatially dependent, will the current no longer be localized on the boundary of the system? For example, we can only have electric field in a portion of the quantum hall system(e.g. by p-n junction geometry), then will the current be flowing along the edge of the system or the boundary of the electric field?